# Strange behaviour passing merged string arrays into makeExecutableSchema of Graphql-Tools.

Tags: graphql, apollo

All schema and resolvers are valid when run in a singular file. Merged schema is valid if corresponding resolvers are missing, or passed without merging.

But when I merge the schema *AND* merge the resolvers, makeExecutableSchema fails with "X is defined in resolvers, but not in schema"

```
 *_ Merged Resolver_* 
{ goalDocs: [AsyncFunction: goalDocs],
    goalDocByID: [AsyncFunction: goalDocByID],
    createGoalDoc: [AsyncFunction: createGoalDoc],
    updateGoalDoc: [AsyncFunction: updateGoalDoc],
    users: [AsyncFunction: users],
    createUser: [AsyncFunction: createUser] }



_*Merged Schema Array*_



 [ '  type Query {    goalDocs: [GoalDocType]    goalDocByID(id:String): GoalDocType}  type GoalDocType {    id: ID!    goal: String    steps: [String]  }  input GoalDocInput {    goal: String    steps: String}  type Mutation {    createGoalDoc(input:GoalDocInput): GoalDocType    updateGoalDoc(id:ID!, input: GoalDocInput): GoalDocType}  schema {    query: Query    mutation: Mutation  }',
  '    type User {      id: ID!      userName: String      friends: [String]      interests: [String]    }    type Query {      users: [User]}    type Mutation {        createUser(input: UserInput): User        updateUser(id: ID!, input: UserInput): User    }    input UserInput {      userName : String      friends: String     interests: String   }   ' ]
```

(sorry about the formatting ^)

`Error: "goalDocs" defined in resolvers, but not in schema`

Again, schema and resolvers are valid when included in the same file (server/index.js)

Comment: I believe I am also seeing this. Did you find a solution? I've spent a lot of time setting up a files layout that depends on merging working properly, I hope I do not have to undo it all. Did you discuss it on Slack? Did you file an issue?

Comment: Yes I filed an issue. Jonas Hefner followed up some time after I had given up on it, but ignored the followup.  I'm the same handle on Github if you want to chase it

Comment: Here's the specific issue I filed. https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/330